# Bitmap font OCR library

Tags: fonts, bitmap, ocr

I'm looking for a simple bitmap font OCR library. I'm trying to recognize text in a bitmap, black and white (or two-colored, but not antialiased). I only need one font at a time (I know which part of the bitmap has which font). It should be really simple, and doesn't have to be fault tolerant since the bitmap was never printed or scanned - it's just screen scraping. It should be able to handle subtle differences like between `l` and `1` or `O` and `0`.

This seems really simple, and I could probably write it myself, but I think something like this should have been done before. Is there a library for that (python or C(++) prefered)?

Answer (score 0):

I created a project which does this:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/monocre

It is usable as a command-line program or library.